# I'm updating the state in a right way?

Tags: reactjs, state

I have some `state` that looks like this:

```
{
  formStatus: {
    isFormOK: false,
    fields: {
      field1: {
        status: 'normal',
        errorText: '',
        value: ''
      },
      field2: {
        status: 'error',
        errorText: 'must be an email',
        value: ''
      },
    }
  }
}
```

And yes, this is a `state` for the parent form, it has some form fields as its children.

Let's say I wanna update a property of a field, for instance: `field1.status`, since the above `state` is a nested object, I will create a new `state` along with the updated value to maintain the whole `state` immutable.

But obviously, every time I `setState`, since the `state` has become a whole new object, it will trigger the `render()` for all the children component(all the fields items), so I change the implementation of all the children from `stateless component` to `React.PureComponent`. It seems handles this problem.

Am I doing things in a right way? Seems it takes a lot to get there.

Do I really have to update the whole `state`?

Comment: If you change the state of the parent component and thus trigger a re-render, you're going to re-render all children regardless. **Rendering in React is not necessarily a bad thing**, as only the *changes* between the previous render and the next one will be passed on to the DOM. It feels like you're manually trying to choose when React should do its job and when it shouldn't.

Comment: @Jaxx I know that react will deep compare the state, so change it may not reflect to the DOM. Just don't know how much could it cost. So, you mean, even I don't change the field item to PureComponent, just calling their render function is not cost much?

Comment: Exactly. If they render exactly the same as during the previous render loop (and it will be the case if their props are left unchanged), then no change will be passed on to the DOM. So, unless you perform very heavy computation in your children components (something you should not be doing anyway), you're just making life difficult for yourself. In essence, let React do its job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to update the whole `state`. If you do not update the whole state and mutate the existing state, the parent component will not know that the state has changed and will not re-render, and will not pass any of the changes to the child components.